# Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric, What should I do in this situation?

Tags: r

```
setwd("C:/DSI_Data_HW3")
beach <- read.csv("HW3_Beachtown.csv")
head(beach, 46)
str(beach)

table(beach$SPEOPLE)

summary(beach)
beach_z <- as.data.frame(lapply(beach, scale))
```

[image]

Comment: You can't scale categorical variables ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Roland pointed out, you can not scale categorical variables... In your case subsetting the `data.frame` to the columns with numeric values would help.

```
beach_z <- as.data.frame(apply(beach[c('SPEOPLE','SCAR')], scale))
# or maybe easier...
beach_z <- scale(beach[c('SPEOPLE','SCAR')])
```